# Ant, Android and Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I am developing Android app on Eclipse using a Windows environment with ADT. I need to build the apk file using Ant from eclipse. So my question is there a way to use the Ant apk builder from within the eclipse?

Thanks,
Nahum

Comment: Why do you need to build with ant if you are using Eclipse & ADT ?

Comment: Pls see my comment for the next answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve best customization if you utilize original ant build. Such build.xml file can be generated by "ant create project ...". You can then tune the build.xml as you wish.
The full document is http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have configured everything correctly then this is the default way to build an APK using eclipse. i.e every time you run your project or install it on a device using ADB it will create the apk via the ant build script.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Answer (score 0):

I use ANT in Eclipse just to JAR up packages that make the API for my applications (other devs use these to subscribe to my application - observer pattern).

To create the actual APK just right click your project and go to 'export'. You should then be walked through the build process and your APK will be saved wherever you have chose.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I'm doing - just didn't know that it uses ant automatically. I need to configure the ant apk builder to not zip some file - how can I do it?

Comment: @nmnir you can look at the builders in properties->builders ... but it doesn't let me change these.  you would just have to figure out how to edit these.